# Oracle Sql to restrict both NULL or '00000'

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a scenario where we have to Filter out any records where the agent number is NULL or '00000' for 3 fields C.SP_AGTNMBR1 , C.SP_AGTNMBR2 and C.SP_AGTNMBR3 , I tried using a where Clause after the join condition in the below query But it dint give me the desired results can someone Please help me and let me know if I am missing something here .

```
**WHERE
    (C.SP_AGTNMBR1 IS NOT NULL OR C.SP_AGTNMBR1 != '00000') 
    AND (C.SP_AGTNMBR2 IS NOT NULL OR C.SP_AGTNMBR2 != '00000') 
    AND (C.SP_AGTNMBR3 IS NOT NULL OR C.SP_AGTNMBR3 != '00000')**


SELECT

    TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_PREF) )|| TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_NO) )|| TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_SUF) ) AS POLICY_NUMBER,
    'CL000' || C.SP_AGTNMBR1 AS AGENT_NUMBER_1,
    TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT1) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_1,
    'CL000' || C.SP_AGTNMBR2 AS AGENT_NUMBER_2,
    TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT2) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_2,
    'CL000' || C.SP_AGTNMBR3 AS AGENT_NUMBER_3,
    TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT3) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_3,
    NULL AS SITUATION
FROM
    EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_SCIS_MASTER M
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_SCIS_SPIA_CONTRACT C ON (
            M.SC_CNT_PREF = C.SP_CNTRPREF
        AND
            M.SC_CNT_NO = C.SP_CNTRNMBR
        AND
            M.SC_CNT_SUF = C.SP_CNTRSUFF
    );
```

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer. Also note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND` rather than `OR`:

```sql
WHERE C.SP_AGTNMBR1 IS NOT NULL
AND   C.SP_AGTNMBR1 != '00000'
AND   C.SP_AGTNMBR2 IS NOT NULL
AND   C.SP_AGTNMBR2 != '00000'
AND   C.SP_AGTNMBR3 IS NOT NULL
AND   C.SP_AGTNMBR3 != '00000'
```

Which, since `!=` will not be true for `NULL` values, can be simplified to:

```sql
WHERE C.SP_AGTNMBR1 != '00000'
AND   C.SP_AGTNMBR2 != '00000'
AND   C.SP_AGTNMBR3 != '00000'
```

If you want to use `OR` then test for equality and negate the `OR`ed result:

```sql
WHERE NOT (C.SP_AGTNMBR1 IS NULL OR C.SP_AGTNMBR1 = '00000') 
AND   NOT (C.SP_AGTNMBR2 IS NULL OR C.SP_AGTNMBR2 = '00000') 
AND   NOT (C.SP_AGTNMBR3 IS NULL OR C.SP_AGTNMBR3 = '00000')
```

---

However, if you want to apply that filter as part of an `OUTER JOIN` to the outer-joined table then the filter should be in the `ON` clause (and not the `WHERE` clause).

If you put the filter in the `WHERE` clause then you are implicitly converting the `OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

So either:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_PREF) )|| TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_NO) )|| TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_SUF) ) AS POLICY_NUMBER,
       'CL000' || C.SP_AGTNMBR1 AS AGENT_NUMBER_1,
       TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT1) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_1,
       'CL000' || C.SP_AGTNMBR2 AS AGENT_NUMBER_2,
       TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT2) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_2,
       'CL000' || C.SP_AGTNMBR3 AS AGENT_NUMBER_3,
       TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT3) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_3,
       NULL AS SITUATION
FROM   EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_SCIS_MASTER M
       LEFT OUTER JOIN EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_SCIS_SPIA_CONTRACT C
       ON (
             M.SC_CNT_PREF = C.SP_CNTRPREF
         AND M.SC_CNT_NO = C.SP_CNTRNMBR
         AND M.SC_CNT_SUF = C.SP_CNTRSUFF
         AND C.SP_AGTNMBR1 != '00000'
         AND C.SP_AGTNMBR2 != '00000'
         AND C.SP_AGTNMBR3 != '00000'
       );
```

or:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_PREF) )|| TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_NO) )|| TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_SUF) ) AS POLICY_NUMBER,
       'CL000' || C.SP_AGTNMBR1 AS AGENT_NUMBER_1,
       TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT1) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_1,
       'CL000' || C.SP_AGTNMBR2 AS AGENT_NUMBER_2,
       TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT2) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_2,
       'CL000' || C.SP_AGTNMBR3 AS AGENT_NUMBER_3,
       TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT3) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_3,
       NULL AS SITUATION
FROM   EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_SCIS_MASTER M
       INNER JOIN EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_SCIS_SPIA_CONTRACT C
       ON (
             M.SC_CNT_PREF = C.SP_CNTRPREF
         AND M.SC_CNT_NO = C.SP_CNTRNMBR
         AND M.SC_CNT_SUF = C.SP_CNTRSUFF
       )
WHERE  C.SP_AGTNMBR1 != '00000'
AND    C.SP_AGTNMBR2 != '00000'
AND    C.SP_AGTNMBR3 != '00000';
```